# How to design a LaTeX template for conference proceedings?

Tags: templates, article, journal-publishing

I want to design a template to publish conference proceedings. This template will combine all the proceedings just like a journal of articles.

My initial plan is to prepare a template based on "article class" for the individual proceeding (this template will be provided to the authors) and then design another template for the overall publication containing all the proceedings.

Is there any better approach to design a template for publishing the conference proceedings?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! i would rather stick with on of may "templates" developed for conferences. for example from electrical engineering domain i recommend to use `IEEEtran` with option `conference`.

Comment: Let suppose that I already have my template for the individual article. I'm wondering about to combine the individual articles as each has its own title page, abstract, references etc. How can I finally combine them all together without any conflict?

Comment: hm, i don't understand you well. do you like to make a proceeding of conference, where you like to include articles as they are?

Comment: You could take a look at the `combine` class which enables several complete LaTeX files to be combined into a single publication like a conference proceedings.

Comment: @Zarko yup, I'll provide the authors with a latex template to write their articles just as provided by renowned journals. I'll design this template using the document class article. Finally, I'm intended to design the main journal template where I can include all the articles.

Comment: @PeterWilson thanks for your suggestion, I'll look at that.